# computationally Intensive routine, ThreadPool or new Thread?

Tags: c#, unity, multithreading

I had to write a computationally expensive routine that runs in 20-30ms. This routine cannot run in the main thread since it would kill the frame rate. The routine runs on demand, when some data change.

I wonder what would be better to use in this scenario. While I think ThreadPool will be all right, I wonder what would happen on an extreme scenario where just one core is available. Would it be better than to create a new thread every time and set the priority to below normal? I wonder though if, in this case, I would end up with the routine struggling to complete within a decent time (although waiting 1-2 seconds would be all right)

My guess is that the ThreadPool is always better in a multi-core scenario, however I wonder if in a single core scenario, creating a thread with lower priority could be a better solution (since I don't care if the computation last longer than excepted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single thread system your lower priority thread might never run.

You could check the number of hardware threads and if there's only one you can call Thread.Sleep(x) where x is a number of milliseconds to sleep so the background thread has a chance to run.

That number could be adjusted according to the main thread's frame time to give a % of time to the background thread.

For example if the rendering took 40ms (slow system, 25fps) you could sleep the main thread for 10ms (1/4 of frame time) when the processing thread is active to control (more or less) the amount of time allocated to the background thread to roughly 20%.

(Assuming no other OS threads and apps are running at the same time.)

Or the other way around: you could have the processing thread at a higher or equal priority and sleep that one for ~8ms every ~8ms on a single-thread system but you have to check the time every so often in your processing loop.

Mixing both also helps in some situations as some OSes/kernels will keep going for 10-20ms (or more) before switching threads. For example this was useful to give the audio thread a chance but OS schedulers got a lot better. Since around 2010 I've only seen this issue on some embedded systems (Your mileage may vary).

Regarding the thread pool: For multiple short background tasks that can run in parallel many at the same time (eg: multiple AIs A* path findings in parallel or particle updates) a thread pool with job batching is the way to go on a multi-core system, but if it's 1 big job (eg: the 1 environment generator/streamer) a dedicated thread is simpler to deal with. This makes it easier to debug, inspect, profile and balance.

Comment: low priority threads get bumped up in priority if they haven't run in a while on most OSes

Comment: thank you, nice answer. The only opinable part is about blocking the main thread, which is impossible (would make the game unresponsive), but the answer about the priority is what I was looking for